# Tinymce not displaying html correctly?

Tags: javascript, struts2, tinymce, wysiwyg

i have below content coming from server which i am showing under textarea attached with tinymce

```
&lt;p&gt;Test1&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Test2&lt;/p&gt;
```

i see in browser with below p tags

```
<p>Test1</p> <p>Test2</p>
```

Thougs it should show as

```
Test1

Test2
```

**I am not sure what i am missing here? I dont see any error in firebug console.When i inspect my textarea from firebug,
it textarea is attached correctly with tinymce but somehow not displaying html content in right format?** I am using struts 2 textArea i.e

Here is my tinymce configuration:-

```
function attachTinyMCE() {
         tinyMCE.init({
         mode: "textareas",
         theme: "advanced",
         plugins: "preview",
         readonly: true,
         theme_advanced_buttons1: "forecolor,backcolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,sub,sup,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough",
         theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
         theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
         theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
         theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
         theme_advanced_path: false,
         theme_advanced_resizing: true,
         entity_encoding: "raw"
      });
     }
```

**UPDATE:-** If i send the below content from server i.e

```
 <p>Test1</p>

 <p>Test2</p>
```

instead of

```
&lt;p&gt;Test1&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Test2&lt;/p&gt;
```

It is shown correctly in tinymce i,e

```
Test1

Test2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue. It was actually struts 2 tag that do the html escape.

Answer (score 1):

`&lt;p&gt;` gets treated as string onInit of the editor. If you want it to be evaluated as a tag you need to replace  `&lt;p&gt;` with `<` etc... before you init the editor.

Comment: well in  tinymce textarea i see &lt;p&gt as <p>. So browser seems to be converting it automatically. But problem is somehow tinymce treating  <p> as string instead of html tag . Please see my update also.